# I wonder why the page is not even opened in my webdriver session

Tags: haskell, selenium

I try to automate tests with the help of [hs-webdriver](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/webdriver), code see below. I have a selenium-server instance started. Everytime I run the `main` function in `ghci` I get an `*** Exception: TimeoutTriggered` and also the given page isn't opened. Do you have any idea, what's going wrong?

```
:set -XOverloadedStrings    
:m + Test.WebDriver Control.Monad Test.WebDriver.Commands.Wait
let main :: IO() ; main = runSession defaultConfig $ do { openPage "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" ; waitUntil 60 (findElem $ ByXPath ".//div") ; return () }
```

Comment: Where are you instantiating the `driver`?

Comment: Good question, do you mean "Started SocketListener on 0.0.0.0:4444"? I compiled the tests coming with the hs-webdriver now and running `.\dist\build\test-search-baidu\test-search-baidu.exe` got me a: `test-search-baidu.exe: TimeoutTriggered`.

Comment: I could not reproduce the timeout on an ubuntu installation, there it works as expected. If I find the cause on the mswindows installation I will post it here.

Comment: [Seems like](http://superuser.com/a/536198/432066) the only workaround is to tell selenium-server to start its socketlistener at localhost.